# Is it possible to link redis with a custom version of openssl

Tags: redis, openssl, tls1.2

I am reading redis's TLS.md and found that it does not seem to match my needs. I hope to link redis with an openssl library (such as openssl-3.0.8), not libssl-dev. Is this possible? When I read the related information, I didn't find the relevant instructions

Because I have an openssl library that I have changed, I want to try to make Redis use my openssl library for tls handshake，but I can't read the relevant information from the official documentation of redis, so I want to know whether it supports

Comment: Assuming you're using CMake, you should be able to specify the *exact* location of the OpenSSL you desire to consume using the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` environment definition.  So long as you have a valid OpenSSL build installed in that folder, it should pick it up. Note that my experience on Windows has been anything-but-pleasant (cmake tends to pick up OpenSSL from the oddest places, most notable the install from Strawberry Perl, no matter what is specified as `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`. But, I've never had it fail on Linux or MacOS.

Comment: In fact, I got redis from github, so he does not have CMakelist.txt, but compiles directly from makefile, so I am confused how to implement my operation, because according to the instructions on github, only make BUILD_TLS=yes is required to build tls , a little unclear how to specify openssl